# How to debug Visual Studio in 64-bit

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, operating-system

OK, after creating an application I want it to be compatible for 64 and 32 bit systems. By default Visual Studio debugs applications in x86 (which is 32-bit). So how can I make Visual Studio debug in x64, for 64-bit systems.
Thanks.

Comment: What language did you write your application in ?

Comment: What do you mean by "by default Visual Studio debugs applications in x86"? That doesn't even make sense. If your app is 64-bit, Visual Studio will debug your 64-bit app -- it doesn't somehow force your 64-bit app to run as 32-bit.

Comment: What is the configuration of your project? Any CPU? x64? x86? And do you have a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system installed on your developer machine?

Comment: OK let me clear things up a bit, first I'm programming on a 64-bit OS and language is VB. When I start up Visual Studio 2010 >> New Project, the configuration manager is like this: Solution Configurations: Debug and Solution Platforms: x86. So I assume that this is debugging in 32-bit right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what language but if it's C# ...

The default build setting for C# projects is an x86 build in debug mode in Visual Studio 2010.  To debug in 64 bit you simple need to change the build setting to 64 bit.

- Right click on the project and select properties
- Switch to the build tab
- Change "Platform Target" to x64

Comment: The default build setting for C# projects is not "x86", but "Any CPU" (at least, in VS 2008), which means the IL code will be run in 64 bit mode automatically when you have a 64 bit system, otherwise in 32 bit mode.

Comment: @DocBrown yes. I forgot that it changed in 2010 to default to x86 for most applications.  I'll update

Comment: In VS 2012, C# default is to build for AnyCPU but debug on x86. On a 64-bit system, follow JaredPar's instructions to force debugging in 64-bit mode. AnyCPU is a confusing term. It means VS will build an executable compatible with AnyCPU but says nothing about debugging mode. Debug mode is specified by "Platform Target" setting.

Comment: In VS 2012, VB.Net uses the term "All Platforms" equivalent to C#'s "AnyCPU". VB.Net uses "Target CPU" equivalent to C#'s "Platform Target".

Comment: That changes the generated output from AnyCPU to x64 hence failing to achieve the goal of debugging an AnyCPU target -which can run as any of 32 bit, WoW64 or native 64 bit- as native 64 bit.